# Adicionar uma resposta HTTP a um painel

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Minha duvida é a seguinte, gero 6 paneis determinados no arquivo script.js que está com nomes definidos como Paineis1, Paineis2...
o que gostaria, fazer um get em uma url, e para cada url que eu chamar  ele adicionar a resposta dentro do painel

Tenho o seguinte **index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='myController'>
    <div class='painel' ng-repeat='i in paineis'>{{i}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**scripts.js:**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.paineis = ['Painel1','Painel2','Painel3','Painel4','Painel5','Painel6'];
});
```

**response.js:**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/commentsssss")
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.content = response.status;
  }, function(response) {
      $scope.content = response.status;
  });
});
```

Comment: Quando você deseja executar a requisição? Assim que a página carrega? O que é o arquivo `response.js`? O *controller* `myCtrl` é o que deveria ser responsável em tratar as requisições?

Comment: assim que a pagina carrega seria o desejavel, acredito que sim, sou iniciante, nao sei se essa foi a melhorar maneira de separar os controllers

Comment: Faz tempo que não trabalho com Angular, mas acredito que não deva criar outro *controller* para isso. Pode definir a função dentro do próprio `myController`. A URL requisitada para cada painel será a mesma?

Comment: não, pretendo alterar essa url de acordo com os numeros de paineis

Comment: Está utilizando Angular versão 1, correto? Diretiva não resolve seu problema?